# Install Docker image from RHEL 7.3 .rpm file

Tags: docker

I want to install Docker image on RHEL 7.3 using .rpm files.

I have got access to Docker .rpm files, but there are list of files in the stable package.

Could any one let me know which .rpm file should I use for the installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can search a ready-made RHEL docker image from dockerhub portal; and pull it as `docker pull <image-name>`.

Alternatively, you can build your own RHEL as below.

1. Download binary mkimage-yum.sh from `https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/contrib/mkimage-yum.sh`
2. Modify the mkimage-yum.sh to create a rhel 7 minimal tarfile, comment out the very last two/three lines (as below) and add a new line as follows:

   ```
   #tar –numeric-owner -c -C "$target" . | docker import - $name:$version
   #docker run -i -t $name:$version echo success
   tar --numeric-owner -c -C "$target" . -zf ${name}.tar.gz
   ```
3. Run the script as `./mkimage-yum.sh rhel7_docker`.
4. Build a docker image out of the tar file as `cat rhel7_docker.tar.gz | sudo docker import - rhel7`

   ```
   The last argument `rhel7` is the image name that are gonna generate.
   ```

Comment: I need to install Docker using the .rpm file and not using github due to the restriction in my environment. I cant use the option that you have mentioned

Comment: I am not telling you to link github from your environment; --------------- just copy the script, script just copies the RHEL tar from RHEL official page.

Comment: I dont have docker installed on my RHEL server. I need to install Docker on my RHEL using .rpm files. Your solution is about create a RHEL image but I want to install Docker on RHEL

Answer (score 0):

To install docker from a .rpm file, you need to download the rpm file(s) and install using YUM. I did it for Docker Enterprise edition. I downloaded the rpm files from the stable package from docker storebits to my local folder. We need both selinux and docker-ee rpm files. Then point the YUM install directory to the download folder.
Note Selinux rpm to be install first and followed by docker-ee rpm

yum install "path to the rpm files"

Comment: Thanks. I could able to fix the issue